# Can't set ttl in sdp as described in RFC 2327

Tags: sip, sdp, ucma

If I try to parse the following sdp with help of Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.dll:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.253.202
s=session
c=IN IP4 224.2.36.42/127
t=0 0
m=message 5060 sip null
a=accept-types:text/plain
```

I'm using the following code:

```
Sdp<SdpGlobalDescription, SdpMediaDescription> sessionDescription2 = new Sdp<SdpGlobalDescription, SdpMediaDescription>();

var encodedText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);  <---- text is the sdp above
if (sessionDescription2.TryParse(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length, true))
```

But I get: Line 4: Value is not a valid IP address or host name

In RFC2327 you can find

```
The TTL for the session is appended to the address using a slash as
a separator.  An example is:

c=IN IP4 224.2.1.1/127
```

So what can I do to set and read the ttl from the sdp?

Answer (score 0):

Simply the Microsoft.Rtc doesn't understand this extension. A lot of SIP/WebRTC/SDP software don't have support for this.

Instead of using the TTL value in the SDP I recommend to use this in the signaling. You can specify it in the request URI:

```
sip:target@domain.com;maddr=224.2.1.1;ttl=127
```

You can set it with the SetAddressInfo:

```
hr = myconnection->SetAddressInfo(uri,1,TTL);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have to use the SDP with a third party software, which uses the TTL in the c= definition.